# Spring data complex query creation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have created a spring-data-jpa repository to my Student domain model and I want to create a more complex query, something like this:

```
List findBySchoolAndLastNameLikeOrId(School s);
```

My problem is how can I define the *parentheses* between the where clauses. I mean, the query will be executed like this

```
List findBy(SchoolAndLastNameLike)OrId
```

or like this

```
List findBySchoolAnd(LastNameLikeOrId)
```

And how can I put the parentheses where I want or create even more complex queries? Please don't answer my with custom repository implementations or usage of the `@Query` annotation - I want to know if what I'd like to do is possible to define this complex query through the method name.

TIA!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: you can't. The query derivation mechanism is targeted at simple use cases. For more complex queries, use `@Query` or define a JPA named query.

Comment: Could you at least explain the way the above (```findBySchoolAndLastNameLikeOrId```) will be run ?

Comment: You already documented the way it currently is run in your question: `and` binds stronger than `or`. So it'll be `List findBy(SchoolAndLastNameLike)OrId` effectively.

Comment: Oh well... that's what I thought :(